# DB2 recursive UDF Table

Tags: sql, recursion, db2

I am having problem writing a recursive table function in DB2.

I have a table of values....

```
With t (Adjustment) as (
VALUES (100)
    , (200)
    , (300)
) select * from t;
```

I need to pass to a UDF Table function an opening value (say 5000) and a factor (say 0.1)

I need to show a result as follows....

```
Opening Shift   Adjustment  Closing
(3)     (1)     (2)
==================================================
5000    500     100     5600            
5600    560     200     6360
6360    636     300     7296
```

1. Shift = Opening * 0.1
2. Closing = Opening + Shift + Closing
3. Opening is the closing of the previous row

My recursive function gets stuck when I tried to bring the brought forward ...(SQL0345N  The fullselect of the recursive common table expression)

Appreciate any idea how to do this.  I am aware the Stored Procedure can do this but I need to use a UDF so that it can be extended in another UDF.

Comment: What defines the collation of the data in table T such that the _previous row_ can be determined; row_number() over() with no particular order perhaps?  Also, 2) in the OP is defined as `Opening + Shift + Closing` but clearly, according to the results, the expression should be ` Opening + Shift + Adjustment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if I interpreted the scenario properly, but here is what I did:

To start, I will create a couple variables to mimic input to a function, and then compose a Recursive Common Table Expression (RCTE) to generate the report using data obtained from those variables:

```
 create variable OpenedWith decimal     default 5000    
 ;
 create variable Factor     decimal(2, 1) default 0.1   
 ;
```

```
 with                                                           
   t (adjustment) as ( values(100), (200), (300) )              
 , ordRows (rn, Adjustment ) as                                 
    ( select row_number() over(), Adjustment from t )           
 , addRows (rn, Opening, Shift, Adjustment, closing ) as        
    ( select rn, OpenedWith, OpenedWith*Factor , Adjustment     
           , ( OpenedWith + ( OpenedWith*Factor ) + Adjustment )
      from ordRows                                              
      where rn = 1                                              
    union all                                                   
      select b.rn, a.Closing, a.Closing * Factor , b.Adjustment 
           , ( a.Closing + (a.Closing * Factor) + b.Adjustment )
      from addRows a                                            
      join ordRows b                                            
        on a.rn = ( b.rn - 1 )                                  
    )                                                           
 select int(rn) as rn, int(opening) as opening
      , int(shift) as shift, adjustment       
      , int(closing) as closing               
 from addRows
```

The following is the report from the above query:

```
 RN         OPENING           SHIFT      ADJUSTMENT         CLOSING
  1           5,000             500             100           5,600
  2           5,600             560             200           6,360
  3           6,360             636             300           7,296
```

And now to modify the above scripted variable creations and query into a User Defined Table Function (UDTF) that operates against the data in TABLE named T:

```
 create function shifted_vals  
  ( OpenedWith decimal( 5 )    
  , Factor     decimal( 3, 2)  
  )                            
  returns table                
  ( Opening      int           
  , Shift        int           
  , Adjustment   int           
  , Closing      int           
  )                            
 return                        
 with                          
   ordRows (rn, Adjustment ) as
    ( select row_number() over(), Adjustment from t )           
 , addRows (rn, Opening, Shift, Adjustment, closing ) as        
    ( select rn, OpenedWith, OpenedWith*Factor , Adjustment     
           , ( OpenedWith + ( OpenedWith*Factor ) + Adjustment )
      from ordRows                                              
      where rn = 1                                              
    union all                                                   
      select b.rn, a.Closing, a.Closing * Factor , b.Adjustment 
           , ( a.Closing + (a.Closing * Factor) + b.Adjustment )
      from addRows a                                            
      join ordRows b                                            
        on a.rn = ( b.rn - 1 )                                  
    )                                                           
 select opening, shift, adjustment, closing                     
 from addRows                                                   
 order by rn
```

Now invoke the UDTF with the noted opening value and factor as arguments; i.e. no longer depending on created variables, instead values obtained via the input parameters:

```
select t.*                              
from table(shifted_vals(5000, 0.1)) as t
; -- results as report, follows:
  OPENING           SHIFT      ADJUSTMENT         CLOSING
    5,000             500             100           5,600
    5,600             560             200           6,360
    6,360             636             300           7,296
```

Comment: Thanks CRPence.
When I ran your first query, I encountered an error...

SQL0345N  The fullselect of the recursive common table expression "<SCHEMA>.ADDROWS" must be the UNION of two or more fullselects and cannot include column functions, GROUP BY clause, HAVING clause, ORDER BY clause, or an explicit join including an ON clause.

Comment: It works!! CRPence

I just have to remove the ON clause...

union all
select b.rn, a.Closing, a.Closing * 0.1 , b.Adjustment, ( a.Closing + (a.Closing * 0.1) + b.Adjustment )
from addRows a, ordRows b
where a.rn = ( b.rn - 1 )

Comment: Ah! Those nuances of the DB2 variants, and lack of a tag to clarify which is being used. I should have noted which I was using; the JOIN syntax shown is acceptable on the DB2 for i SQL on which those queries were run, and the output shown was produced, on IBM i 7.1  Unless you suggest otherwise [e.g. that I edit the answer], I will allow these comments to serve as the assist for anyone encountering errors.